# Find hash algorithm?

Tags: hash

I'm trying to find out which method of hashing was used to generate certain strings. It's 32 bits (4 Bytes).

Found out it was DBJ v1. Any idea how to implement in C#? Thanks :)

Example Hashes:
00 02 B5 D5 - hash
30 - string

35 A0 FD 6A - hash
6F 66 66 65 6E 73 69 76 - string

05 7B DC 6C - hash
70 6C 61 79 65 72 20 75 73 65 64 20 6F 66 66 65 6E 73 69 76 65 20 6C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 - string

This is important so thank you!

Comment: What is the source of the strings and hashes?

Comment: I found out the hash algorithm was DJB v1. Any way I could implement in C# ?

Comment: Here's an implementation in C (C++?) - should be pretty easy to translate to C#: [devnotes](http://devnotes.wikispaces.com/DJB+Hash+Function)

Comment: @Joe Enos Thanks! I know C too so that will help. A client just wanted it done in C#. Thanks a whole heap!

Comment: That is more commonly called [the “djb2” hash](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html).

Comment: @robmayoff djb2 is a different hash from dbj1

Comment: The hash function named `DJBHash` in @JoeEnos's link is also known as `djb2`.  That hash function matches your examples.  [Here's my test.](http://jsfiddle.net/TL9Vq/2/)  It doesn't matter whether you think it's "DBJ v1"; it's [widely known as `djb2`](https://www.google.com/search?q=djb2+hash) and it matches your examples.

Comment: More pedantically, it matches your examples if you add the missing 65 (which is, in hex, the ASCII/Unicode code point for lower case “e”) to the end of the second example, thus making the second example spell the word “offensive”.

Comment: oh okay! Thanks for the info. Sorry for the confusion. :)